# File reading from remote server

Tags: node.js, download, fs, remote-server

Using nodejs I need my code to check for file changes for a file on a remote server, If it is it would download the file, as I am making a global node system,
As it would not be easy to change many files, I don't what to use github, tried it before and did not work so i shall not be using it maybe using fs I don't really know

Comment: no, thats quite not possible. hacky solution would be :- you have make request to server every X sec/min/hour, store and compare modified time or md5 checksum of the file  to determine whether file has changed or not.

Comment: Aw man i thaught it was also ii saw a post but dident have the answer so i asked